# Jsoup select multiple siblings after a paticular sibling

Tags: jsoup

I'm trying to get multiple nodes out as one block of text, where these nodes are particular siblings grouped at the end of a list of similar siblings.  Its proving tricky in pure JSoup selector syntax.   Im a newb to this :P

Given this *fragment* of HTML:

```
<h2>Product information</h2>
<div class="detailsWrapper">
  <div class="content">
     <p>Gently baked breakfast biscuits</p>
     <p>Proven to slowly release carbohydrates </p>
     <p>Made with a blend of 5 wholegrains </p>
     <p>Contains 6 packs of 4 breakfast b</p>
     <p>Suitable for vegetarians</p> 
     <p>At xxxx, we're passion blablabla </p>
     <h3>Allergy Information</h3>
     <p>Contains: Barley, Oats, Spelt, Wheat, Milk, Rye, Soya\Soybeans</p>
     <p>May Contain: Eggs, Nuts, Peanuts</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want and can get the two last p tags using the following:

```
h2:containsOwn(Product Information) + div.detailsWrapper > div.content h3:containsOwn(Allergy Information) ~ p
```

But they are returned as separate items.  Is there a way to get just the last two p tags as a single block of text ?

Thanks dan

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. They're not a single or nested block of elements in the document model. `text()` only returns "[the combined text of this element and all its children](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text%28%29)", it says nothing about siblings!

Is it such a hardship? One way you could get around it is to select the h3 Allergy Information element alone, and then ask for its [`siblingElements()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#siblingElements%28%29). This returns all the siblings that come after it as an `Elements` object, and [`Elements.text()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#text%28%29) returns "the combined text of all the matched elements."

```
doc.select("h3:containsOwn(Allergy Information)").get(0).siblingElements().text()
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer for above html is

```
doc.select("h3 ~ p")
```

Jsoup has a `~` which selects preceding sibling. So `E ~ F` means an F element preceded by sibling E. Using that you could say `doc.select("h3 ~ p")` to get last two tags for above html.

Comment: Thanks but no thanks :)  thats what I'm already doing.  Have another read of the above and scroll the example Jsoup selector over and you'll see I'm already doing " ~ p".  As mentioned on the q above, this returns multiples rather than a single text block.

Comment: What do you mean by a text block?

Comment: A single returned entity not multiple selected nodes.  I'm trying to keep as much configuration in pure JSoup selector syntax as possible and not put any logic in Java.  At the moment this doesn't seem possible and Stuarts answer above ".get(0).siblingElements().text()" sounds like a way to return all subsequent siblings as a single text entity.